# need to count and average the finalaverage output

Tags: java

I have been able to create a program to calculate the letter grade and average of each student entered but I am having trouble trying to create a counter for the finalaverages that records them all to give me a class average. This has been the most difficult part of my entire program. I do not understand how to implement the counter, I need help.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class gradebook {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub


        float discussionweight, hwweight, examweight, discussion, hw, exam, finalaverage;
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print ("Enter the weight of the discussions as an integer: ");
        discussionweight = scan.nextFloat();
        // Prompts for the weight of the homework grade in an integer
                System.out.print ("Enter the weight of the homework as an integer: ");
                hwweight = scan.nextFloat();
                System.out.print("Enter the weight of the exam as an integer:");
                examweight = scan.nextFloat();
        int again=-1;


        while( again!=0){


        System.out.print("Enter the students name: ");
        String student = scan.next();


        // Prompts for the discussions grade
        System.out.print ("Enter the score of the discussion as an integer: ");
        discussion = scan.nextFloat();



        // Prompts for hw grade
        System.out.print ("Enter the hw grade: ");
        hw = scan.nextFloat();

        System.out.print("Enter the exam grade");
        exam = scan.nextFloat();
        finalaverage = (((discussionweight * discussion) + (hw * hwweight) + (exam * examweight)) / 100);       
        if (finalaverage >= 90)
        System.out.println(student +"'s " + "final grade is an A."); 
        else if (finalaverage >= 80)
        System.out.println(student +"'s " + "final grade is a B.");
        else if (finalaverage >= 70)
        System.out.println(student +"'s " + "final grade is a C.");
        else if (finalaverage >= 60)
        System.out.println(student +"'s " + "final grade is a D.");
        else if (finalaverage >= 10)
        System.out.println(student +"'s " + "final grade is an F.");

        System.out.println ("The final average is "+ finalaverage);
        System.out.print("Would you like to continue? Enter 0 to exit or enter 1 to continue.");
         again = scan.nextInt();}

        System.out.print("End Gradebook");

        float integer;

        double sum = 0;
        double average = 0;

        int count = 0;

        // set integer = to the nextInt() while looping so it calculates properly
        while ((integer = ((finalaverage)) != 0) {
            count ++; 
            sum += integer;
        }
        average = sum / count; // calculate the average after the while-loop

        System.out.println("Average = " + average);

    }
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
while( again!=0){
```

I assume this loop repeats **for each student**. This implies that you want to increment the number of students **once** inside this loop. However, you have

```
    while ((integer = ((finalaverage)) != 0) {
        count ++; 
        sum += integer;
    }
```

which potentially increments the student count several times for each student.

To fix this, you should be able to simply remove this nested while loop. Simply increment the count of students and add the current student's grade to the class total.

Only after you are done looping over the students can you calculate the class average. This means that the line `average = sum / count;` should be **outside** the loop.

p.s. I suggest modifying your variable names. `integer` is not very descriptive and completely misleading since it is declared as a `float`. In fact, I think you don't even need this `integer` variable. `sum` and `count` are a little better, but could be changed to `classSum` and `studentCount` to be even more descriptive.

Answer (score 0):

nah, you dont need that second while loop. what you need is add sum every loop with finalaverage and increment count each loop

```
while(again!=0){
...
sum += finalaverage;
count++;
}
```

full source is like this :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        float discussionweight, hwweight, examweight, discussion, hw, exam, finalaverage = 0;
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter the weight of the discussions as an integer: ");
        discussionweight = scan.nextFloat();
        // Prompts for the weight of the homework grade in an integer
        System.out.print("Enter the weight of the homework as an integer: ");
        hwweight = scan.nextFloat();
        System.out.print("Enter the weight of the exam as an integer:");
        examweight = scan.nextFloat();
        int again = -1;

        int count = 0, sum = 0;

        while (again != 0) {  
            count++;

            System.out.print("Enter the students name: ");
            String student = scan.next();

            // Prompts for the discussions grade
            System.out.print("Enter the score of the discussion as an integer: ");
            discussion = scan.nextFloat();

            // Prompts for hw grade
            System.out.print("Enter the hw grade: ");
            hw = scan.nextFloat();

            System.out.print("Enter the exam grade");
            exam = scan.nextFloat();
            finalaverage = (((discussionweight * discussion) + (hw * hwweight) + (exam * examweight)) / 100);
            if (finalaverage >= 90) {
                System.out.println(student + "'s " + "final grade is an A.");
            } else if (finalaverage >= 80) {
                System.out.println(student + "'s " + "final grade is a B.");
            } else if (finalaverage >= 70) {
                System.out.println(student + "'s " + "final grade is a C.");
            } else if (finalaverage >= 60) {
                System.out.println(student + "'s " + "final grade is a D.");
            } else if (finalaverage >= 10) {
                System.out.println(student + "'s " + "final grade is an F.");
            }

            System.out.println("The final average is " + finalaverage);

            sum += finalaverage;

            System.out.print("Would you like to continue? Enter 0 to exit or enter 1 to continue.");
            again = scan.nextInt();
        }

        System.out.print("End Gradebook");

        // set integer = to the nextInt() while looping so it calculates properly
        int average = sum / count; // calculate the average after the while-loop

        System.out.println("Average = " + average);

    }
```